# Delete empty lines in the final HTML

Tags: jekyll

The HTML output of my Jekyll project is filled with whitespace. What is the easiest way to delete empty lines in the HTML output of Jekyll? Is there a hook I can use?

I'm searching for the right place/hook so that `jekyll build` takes care about everything.

Comment: does  `sed '/^$/d' file1 > file2 ` not good enough for you?

Comment: Where is the proper hook to implement that in the Jekyll workflow?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754312/how-to-suppress-blank-line-in-jekyll

Comment: https://github.com/aucor/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/strip.rb works like a charm. Thank you @AlexGoretoy !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful plugin for this:
https://github.com/aucor/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/strip.rb

Once it is installed in the `_plugins` directory you just have to add the following bracket to `_layouts/default.html`

```
{% strip %}

[...]

{% endstrip %}
```